# Stylesheets not downloading on client IE8 browser

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8

I have 3 websites which I have tested on all browsers including the below IE8 setups. Whats happening is that on the clients computer no stylesheet is getting downloaded at all. I viewed the developer tools and the HTML loads fine, I can see the all the links, but no files come through.

I tested on the following at my office on my machines and everything worked fine:

```
OSX lion using Virtual Box with Windows 7 - IE8

OSX Mountain Lion using parellels with Windows 8 - IE10 in IE8 browser mode

Pc - Windows XP running IE8
```

The client is running Windows 7 with IE8 - the network doesnt allow for their computers to change settings or download and install different browsers - thus I couldnt test that or change any firewall settings.

All three websites use wordpress, they are all hosted with different service providers. Two of the three use Foundation. All three are Html5

I cant figure this out, any direction would help.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the corporations security settings, though other html5 websites seemed to work. So possibly something to do with html5.

[godurban.co.ze](http://www.godurban.co.za)

[muvo.co.za](http://www.muvo.co.za)

[boxer.co.za](http://www.boxer.co.za)

Comment: Can you specify "no files come through"? Do the requests timeout or is there anything on the console?

Comment: There was 4 errors i noticed in the console but it didnt give any discription or anything. when i clicked on it to open up the script - it said it wasnt available. There wasnt timeout. Its like it didnt even try to load them.
when I go to the developer tools and go to the css tab, and click on the css files drop down - its completely empty.

In the html header all the links are there and look fine.